# Find number of strings in number of files

Tags: grep, find, xargs

```
#!/bin/ksh
inputpath="/home/beaadmin/SET4/Input.txt" #Give patterns to be searched
contentpath="/home/beaadmin/SET4/FILES" 
outpath="/home/beaadmin/SET4/impacted"
 count=1 
while read line
 do
    echo "Line :$count"
    echo "$line"


    return=$(find $contentpath -iname "*" | xargs grep "$line*")

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
            echo "$line" >> $outpath
    else
            echo ""
    fi
    let count=$count+1

  done < $inputpath
```

let say I have string1,string2,string3 and File1,File2,File3..
I want to find string1 in File1,File2,File3 and if match found then write it to output dir.same way to find for string2,string3..But the above code not finding it

Comment: Hi Admin/Team any update on the above post ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming string1,string2,etc... are on separate lines of Input.txt, there's only a small bug.

Change this:

```
xargs grep "$line*"
```

To this:

```
xargs grep "$line.*"
```

Also, two suggestions about your `find` command. First, `-iname "*"` doesn't have any effect. Second, your `find` command will find some directories, which will cause grep some (probably non-fatal) errors. You could fix that with e.g.,

```
find -type f $contentpath
```